# Laser Barcode Scanner Issue in React (Expo)

Tags: reactjs, expo

Is it possible using laser barcode scanner in expo?

i did something like this , but i cant make it to work.

Basicly im trying to get the scanned data from PDA(android) device , that when i click to scan on PDA i get info to a console log per example to test it ,later on i will need that data to spread to a specific number of inputboxes.
Right now when i clicked on the scan button nothing happens but if i try to use a phone with a camera it works without the click function.

````
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';


export default function App() {
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

    const handleBarCodeScanned = ({  data }) => {
        setScanned(true);
        alert(`${data}`);
    };
    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if(event.key === 'Enter'){
        handleBarCodeScanned
        }
      };

    return (
        
        <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleKeyPress}
        ></BarCodeScanner>
        
    );
}```
````

Comment: Hey Arti, welcome to SO. I'd suggest you add some additional context to your question to make it easier for other users to reply. What are you trying to do? What is the expected behavior? What is happening instead? Have a look here for information about how to ask good questions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much , hope you guys help me and the other way around , meanwhile i added some more info as you suggested .

Comment: Do you have a button? I don't see it in your code. Did you follow the official example? Did you try to `console.log` and see whether the problem is in the `event` not firing or having the wrong `key`? https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/

Comment: I meant using the button from the PDA , like when i click to activate(button -hardware in pda) the laser scanner get me the info from the bar code, this code is a component that i call on my main page .

Comment: You should inspect your code and see what's going on. From what I understand from the official documentation, the `BarCodeScanner` is immediately active and start looking for a barcode. If it finds one, it calls the `handleBarCodeScanned`. In your code, when a code is detected, it calls `handleKeyPress`. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What I would expect is the `keyPress` should start `BarCodeScanner`, not viceversa.